# Private properties in JavaScript ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, private-members, es2022

Is it possible to create private properties in ES6 classes?

Here's an example.
How can I prevent access to `instance.property`?

```
class Something {
  constructor(){
    this.property = "test";
  }
}

var instance = new Something();
console.log(instance.property); //=> "test"
```

Comment: There is actually stage 3 proposal for this feature - https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/ https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Comment: @arty I've provided an answer to this with examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237988/1432509

Comment: All solutions for private properties / methods, ES5 / ES6+, all fail to provide real privacy since Chrome based browsers can always reveal the entire execution context in the `[Scopes]` object of any prototype. Some things just have to be coded outside the browser scope. In my test, no method will hide anything from Chrome.

Answer (score 352, accepted):

[Private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) is now supported by the majority of browsers.

```
class Something {
  #property;

  constructor(){
    this.#property = "test";
  }

  #privateMethod() {
    return 'hello world';
  }

  getPrivateMessage() {
      return this.#property;
  }
}

const instance = new Something();
console.log(instance.property); //=> undefined
console.log(instance.privateMethod); //=> undefined
console.log(instance.getPrivateMessage()); //=> test
console.log(instance.#property); //=> Syntax error
```

Comment: I'm wondering how can those class fields work. You can't currently use `this` in constructor before you call `super()`. Yet babel puts them before super.

Comment: How to configure ESLint to allow `#privateCrap` syntax?

Comment: @Marecky Use babel-eslint :)

Comment: If you can't use Babel, you can try my package [prv](https://npmjs.com/package/prv) which works in older browsers.

Comment: And what about eslint? I got parser error at equal sign. Babel is working, just eslint can't parse this new js syntax.

Comment: Wow this is very ugly. Hashtag is a valid character. The property is not really private, or? .. I checked it in TypeScript. Private members are not compiled in private or read-only (from outside). Just declared like another (public) property. (ES5).

Comment: [By now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0oy0vQKEZE), this solution is also officially supported in Google Chrome and Node.js v12. Private getters and setters are in development.

Comment: How do you write _private methods_ with this? Can I do this: `#beep() {}`; and this: `async #bzzzt() {}`?

Comment: @seeker_of_bacon you can use this word in constructor when you are already in a super class (classes extending nothing). super() syntax required only in extender (sub, child etc.) classes.

Comment: so ES6 won't support it natively but babel 7 and stage 3 preset can transpile it to be private?

Comment: Those don't work with `static` currently. Why, ECMAScript. Why.

Comment: You can see the browser support for private fields [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields). At the time of writing this the only major browsers that don't support them are Firefox and Safari.

Comment: It seems those don't support class composition in any way.

Comment: This ES stage 3 proposal is implemented in [TypeScript version 4.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-3-beta/#ecmascript-private-class-elements) as well and members starting with `#` (not just `private` modifier) are private at runtime as well, not just at compile time (if compiled to >= ES 2015). I created [sample code in TypeScript playfeild](https://cutt.ly/ucbmge5) to demonstrate, that it is truly private (ESNext target works with Chrome, that has implemented support for ES private fields proposal)

Comment: why wouldn't they use well established underscore instead of hash ...... always need to invent something new, just because.

Comment: Using `_` would be a breaking change, unless what you mean is that JS doesn't need _private_ private properties at all

Comment: @br4nnigan `_` can already be at the start of a property name, so suddenly making it indicate a property is private would cause problems

Comment: Interestingly, the latest version of Firefox (93.0) supports private properties, but attempting to reference them in the Watch window causes an error. You can see them by referencing the object containing them and opening it.

Comment: This has already gone to [finished proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md) and in [the specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-private-names).

Comment: cant we just write private property; and that's it?

Comment: Keep in mind if you log the instance of the class in devtools it will show `Something {#property: 'test'}`, kind of defeating the purpose...

Comment: @Domske I agree. It looks like something you'd find in PERL.

Answer (score 325):

### Update: See others answer, this is outdated.

Short answer, no, there is no native support for private properties with ES6 classes.

But you could mimic that behaviour by not attaching the new properties to the object, but keeping them inside a class constructor, and use getters and setters to reach the hidden properties. Note that the getters and setters gets redefine on each new instance of the class.

ES6

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        var _name = name
        this.setName = function(name) { _name = name; }
        this.getName = function() { return _name; }
    }
}
```

ES5

```
function Person(name) {
    var _name = name
    this.setName = function(name) { _name = name; }
    this.getName = function() { return _name; }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution the best. I agree it shouldn't be used for scaling but it's perfect for classes that will usually only be instantiated once per include.

Comment: Should also be noted, if you're using ES6 style classes then there's a good chance you're supporting ES5 get/set too.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Comment: Also you are redefining every single component of this class each time a new is created.

Comment: @ShawnKhameneh, how does this closure trick work with setter and getter in ECMA 6? I only came up with a solution with `defineProperty` available in ECMA 5, which is way more ugly than the syntax in ECMA 6.

Comment: This is so weird! In ES6 you are creating more "closure pyramids" than before ES6! Defining functions WITHIN a constructor looks uglier than it did in the above ES5 example.

Comment: Since the OP specifically asks about ES6 classes, I personally think this is a poor solution, even though it technically works.

The major limitation is that now every class method that uses private variables must be declared inside the constructor, severely undermining the advantages of having `class` syntax in the first place.

Comment: All this does is introduce indirection. Now how do you make the `getName` and `setName` properties private?

Comment: @aij So name one language that does not do the same. You can easily see that he could just comment out the setter or the getter or both and that `_name` is truly private.

Comment: @NanoWizard I have to agree with your criticism. This technique works, but only having access to the private variables in the constructor is very limiting. It can be easily solved though. All you need is a way to associate data with an object without creating a field on that object... This can be achieved with a WeakMap... See my package [prv](https://npmjs.com/package/prv) for details.

Comment: There is a new library out that supports private data while still allowing for the use of ES6 class syntax, i.e. the class functions can see the data on the `this` context, but nothing else can. https://github.com/anywhichway/privatize. It only requires adding one line of code to existing classes, the line that declares which data is private. Even class functions defined outside the constructor have access to the data, but foreign entities do not.

Comment: if there are getters and setters for the private variables, then can't other code just use the setter and do the same thing `obj.setName("bar") `as if they are doing `obj.name = "bar"`?

Comment: Is this the correct answer? Because you absolutely can make private properties by using "#". You can then access the readOnly value with a ```getX()``` method like so

```getProperty() {
   return this.#property;
  }```

Comment: @JosephKreifelsII using `#` to make private properties is a "Stage 3" suggestion and not yet universally supported. Google Apps Script, for example, returns an error when attempting that.

Comment: One issue with the ES6 example. A developer who doesn't understand what's going on could actually overwrite your getter/setter function with a new function or worse, a random variable! You could set `Person.setName = "Haha! I overwrote your setter"` and that class object will become basically unusable. However, there is a fix to this. On the last line of the constructor you can add `Object.freeze(this)` and it will prevent overwriting your getter and setter by making them "constants". Since it's all passed by reference, the setter will still modify the internal variable as desired.

Answer (score 265):

Yes, prefix the name with `#` and include it in the class definition, not just the constructor.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

Real private properties were finally added in ES2022. As of 2023-01-01, private properties (fields and methods) have been supported in all major browsers for at least a year, but 5-10% of users are still on older browsers [[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=javascript%20private)].

Example:

```
class Person {
  #age

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name; // this is public
    this.#age = 20; // this is private
  }

  greet() {
    // here we can access both name and age
    console.log(`name: ${this.name}, age: ${this.#age}`);
  }
}

let joe = new Person('Joe');
joe.greet();

// here we can access name but not age
```

Following are methods for keeping properties private in pre-ES2022 environments, with various tradeoffs.

### Scoped variables

The approach here is to use the scope of the constructor function, which is private, to store private data. For methods to have access to this private data they must be created within the constructor as well, meaning you're recreating them with every instance. This is a performance and memory penalty, but it may be acceptable. The penalty can be avoided for methods that do not need access to private data by declaring them in the normal way.

Example:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    let age = 20; // this is private
    this.name = name; // this is public

    this.greet = () => {
      // here we can access both name and age
      console.log(`name: ${this.name}, age: ${age}`);
    };
  }

  anotherMethod() {
    // here we can access name but not age
  }
}

let joe = new Person('Joe');
joe.greet();

// here we can access name but not age
```

### Scoped WeakMap

A WeakMap can be used to improve the performance of the above approach, in exchange for even more clutter. WeakMaps associate data with Objects (here, class instances) in such a way that it can only be accessed using that WeakMap. So, we use the scoped variables method to create a private WeakMap, then use that WeakMap to retrieve private data associated with `this`. This is faster than the scoped variables method because all your instances can share a single WeakMap, so you don't need to recreate methods just to make them access their own WeakMaps.

Example:

```
let Person = (function () {
  let privateProps = new WeakMap();

  return class Person {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name; // this is public
      privateProps.set(this, {age: 20}); // this is private
    }

    greet() {
      // Here we can access both name and age
      console.log(`name: ${this.name}, age: ${privateProps.get(this).age}`);
    }
  };
})();

let joe = new Person('Joe');
joe.greet();

// here we can access name but not age
```

This example uses a WeakMap with Object keys to use one WeakMap for multiple private properties; you could also use multiple WeakMaps and use them like `privateAge.set(this, 20)`, or write a small wrapper and use it another way, like `privateProps.set(this, 'age', 0)`.

The privacy of this approach could theoretically be breached by tampering with the global `WeakMap` object. That said, all JavaScript can be broken by mangled globals.

(This method could also be done with `Map`, but `WeakMap` is better because `Map` will create memory leaks unless you're very careful, and for this purpose the two aren't otherwise different.)

### Half-Answer: Scoped Symbols

A Symbol is a type of primitive value that can serve as a property name instead of a string. You can use the scoped variable method to create a private Symbol, then store private data at `this[mySymbol]`.

The privacy of this method can be breached using `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`, but is somewhat awkward to do.

Example:

```
let Person = (() => {
  let ageKey = Symbol();

  return class Person {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name; // this is public
      this[ageKey] = 20; // this is intended to be private
    }

    greet() {
      // Here we can access both name and age
      console.log(`name: ${this.name}, age: ${this[ageKey]}`);
    }
  }
})();

let joe = new Person('Joe');
joe.greet();

// Here we can access joe's name and, with a little effort, age. We can’t
// access ageKey directly, but we can obtain it by listing all Symbol
// properties on `joe` with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(joe)`.
```

Note that making a property non-enumerable using `Object.defineProperty` does not prevent it from being included in `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`.

### Half-Answer: Underscores

The old convention is to just use a public property with an underscore prefix. This does not keep it private, but it does do a good job of communicating to readers that they should treat it as private, which often gets the job done. In exchange for this, we get an approach that's easier to read, easier to type, and faster than the other workarounds.

Example:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name; // this is public
    this._age = 20; // this is intended to be private
  }

  greet() {
    // Here we can access both name and age
    console.log(`name: ${this.name}, age: ${this._age}`);
  }
}

let joe = new Person('Joe');
joe.greet();

// Here we can access both joe's name and age. But we know we aren't
// supposed to access his age, which just might stop us.
```

### Summary

- ES2022: great but not yet supported by all visitors
- Scoped variables: private, slower, awkward
- Scoped WeakMaps: hackable, awkward
- Scoped Symbols: enumerable and hackable, somewhat awkward
- Underscores: just a request for privacy, no other downsides

Comment: The first example snippet ("scoped variables") is a total antipattern - each returned object will have a different class. Don't do that. If you want privileged methods, create them in the constructor.

Comment: Wrapping a class inside a function seems to defeat the whole purpose of using classes in the first place. If you already use the function to create an instance, you might as well place all your private/public members inside that function as well, and forget about the whole class keyword.

Comment: @Bergi @Kokodoko I edited the scoped variables approach to be slightly faster and not break `instanceof`. I admit I was thinking of that approach as included only for completeness' sake and should have given more thought to how much it is actually capable of.

Comment: your `this.greet` in the first example should use an arrow function so that it inherits lexical `this` automatically

Comment: Excellent explanation! I'm still surprised that ES6 actually made it harder to simulate a private variable, where in ES5 you could just use var and this inside a function to simulate private and public.

Comment: @Kokodoko If you dispense with the class and just put everything in the function, you will also have to revert to implementing inheritance using the prototype method. Using extend on classes is by far a cleaner approach, so using a class inside a function is totally acceptable.

Comment: Wouldn't passing `this` to weakmap prevent the instance from getting garbage collected? and also, all private properties won't ever get deleted when the instance gets garbage collected if not passing `this` to the weakmap. Isn't that a memory issue?

For the Symbol issue with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`, you can wrap the object with a Proxy that has an `ownKeys` handler which traps both `getOwnProperties` and `getOwnPropertySymbols` where you can return an array of the Object properties minus the Symbol.

Comment: @RamtinSoltani no, it would be true of Map, but those two memory issues are what WeakMap is designed to solve. See "Why WeakMap?" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap).

Comment: @TristanBerger That’s good to know. Thanks for pointing it out. With those issues no longer existing, this would be the best method to store private data.

Comment: I just want to point out that there are a few articles out there stating the garbage collection issue of WeakMaps which are simply not true.

Comment: IMHO, the __scoped symbols__ is the right answer - it gives the desired level of privacy (defending from unintended usage, not otherwise, which is the only concern the private properties should serve) in a least complex/hackish way

Comment: @Drenai You only need the polyfill *in theory*. In practice, all browsers support `WeakMap` and have been doing so for some time.

Answer (score 123):

Update: A [proposal with nicer syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is on its way. Contributions are welcome.

---

Yes, there is - for scoped access in objects - [ES6 introduces `Symbol`s](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-symbols/).

Symbols are unique, you can't gain access to one from the outside except with reflection (like privates in Java/C#) but anyone who has access to a symbol on the inside can use it for key access:

```
var property = Symbol();
class Something {
    constructor(){
        this[property] = "test";
    }
}

var instance = new Something();

console.log(instance.property); //=> undefined, can only access with access to the Symbol
```

Comment: Can't you use `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`? ;)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Apparently Symbols no longer ensure true privacy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22280202/1282216

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy that's reflection :)

Comment: wouldn't this be similar to just using numberic constants as member names?

    const myPrivateMethod = 1;
    Something.prototype[myPrivateMethod] = function () { ... }

    new Something()[myPrivateMethod]();

Comment: @Benja well - one difference is that using `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` would show it and external users would simply be able to do `(new Something())[1]()` to run the function. Also note that all object keys in JavaScript (including array keys) are effectively strings.

Comment: How is it private? Can't you just loop through all the keys of the object and find it?

Comment: @trusktr through thre keys? No. Through the symbols? Yes. Very much like how you can use reflection in languages like C# and Java to access private fields. Access modifiers aren't about security - they're about clarity of intent.

Comment: It seems like using Symbols is similar to doing `const myPrivateMethod = Math.random();
    Something.prototype[''+myPrivateMethod] = function () { ... }

    new Something()[''+myPrivateMethod]();`.This isn't really privacy, it's obscurity, in the sense of traditional JavaScript. I would consider "private" JavaScript to mean using closures to encapsulate variables. Those variables are hence not accessible through reflection.

Comment: Also, I feel that using the `private` and `protected` keywords would be so much cleaner than `Symbol` or `Name`. I prefer dot notation rather than bracket notation. I'd like to keep using a dot for private things. `this.privateVar`

Comment: We have static, but what's the target for implementing public, private and protected?  Also, here's one solution using WeakMap, but it's a bit hairy. http://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/

Comment: @benjamin-gruenbaum symbol is used as a workaround. It creates a variable with a name that cannot be figured out by the user. You could as well use var property = "you will never find out how to access -- property" and suffix it with a random number. But within your class, you always have to use this[property] and can never use this["property"] or this.property. This is likely to make your code pretty hard to debug (because, sometimes, you will add the quotes).

Comment: Why not just prefix the private data with `_`? If it can't be enforced, let's be at least open about the intent. E.g: `this._key = "123";`

Comment: If I need module level private functions then I think it should be enough to declare a normal function and not to export it, wdyt?

Comment: I can't see how this is remotely private?

The property symbol is externally visible. You don't even need to use `getOwnPropertySymbols()`, you can externally access the so-called "private" property, simply by doing `instance[property]`!

I guess the best you could say is that its visibility is private-ish (in that it takes a little extra work to query the interface), but its accessibility is public!

Comment: @DanKing private/public (without weak maps) is a matter of communicating with other developers and not a matter of security. Symbols have become a pretty common way to communicate a property is private without actually limiting it's accessibility.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Seems to me like a lot of effort for no real benefit. Why not just use (e.g.) `this._myPrivateProperty`?

Comment: @DanKing I use `_myPrivateProperty` myself, but it's a convention I've seen used very often.

Comment: There is a stage 3 proposal that fixes this, will update the answer

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes Symbols do work, however are not fully cross browser as they are not supported by Internet Explorer

Comment: to be private declare the property within the class constructor

Answer (score 35):

The answer is "No". But you can create private access to properties like this:

- Use modules. Everything in a module is private unless it's made public by using the `export` keyword.
- Inside modules, use function closure: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/closures_in_javascript.htm

(The suggestion that Symbols could be used to ensure privacy was true in an earlier version of the ES6 spec but is no longer the case:https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2014-January/035604.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22280202/1282216. For a longer discussion about Symbols and privacy see: https://curiosity-driven.org/private-properties-in-javascript)

Comment: -1, this does not answer your question really. (You can use closures with IIFEs in ES5 too). Private properties are enumerable through reflection in most languages (Java, C#, etc). The point of private properties is to convey intent to other progrmamers and not to enforce security.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I know, I wish I had a better answer, I'm not happy with it either.

Comment: I think symbols are still a valid way to achieve inaccessible members while in the programming environment. Yes, they can still be found if you reallllyyy want, but that's not the point is it? You shouldn't store sensitive information in it, but you shouldn't do that anyway in client-side code. But it works for the purpose of hiding a property or method from an outside class.

Comment: Using variables scoped at the level of a module as substitute for private properties in a class will lead to a singleton.behavior or behavior similart to  statitc properties.Instances of vars will get shared.

Answer (score 30):

The only way to get true privacy in JS is through scoping, so there is no way to have a property that is a member of `this` that will be accessible only inside the component. The best way to store truly private data in ES6 is with a WeakMap.

```
const privateProp1 = new WeakMap();
const privateProp2 = new WeakMap();

class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    privateProp1.set(this, "I am Private1");
    privateProp2.set(this, "I am Private2");

    this.publicVar = "I am public";
    this.publicMethod = () => {
      console.log(privateProp1.get(this), privateProp2.get(this))
    };        
  }

  printPrivate() {
    console.log(privateProp1.get(this));
  }
}
```

Obviously this is a probably slow, and definitely ugly, but it does provide privacy.

Keep in mind that EVEN THIS isn't perfect, because Javascript is so dynamic. Someone could still do

```
var oldSet = WeakMap.prototype.set;
WeakMap.prototype.set = function(key, value){
    // Store 'this', 'key', and 'value'
    return oldSet.call(this, key, value);
};
```

to catch values as they are stored, so if you wanted to be extra careful, you'd need to capture a local reference to `.set` and `.get` to use explicitly instead of relying on the overridable prototype.

```
const {set: WMSet, get: WMGet} = WeakMap.prototype;

const privateProp1 = new WeakMap();
const privateProp2 = new WeakMap();

class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    WMSet.call(privateProp1, this, "I am Private1");
    WMSet.call(privateProp2, this, "I am Private2");

    this.publicVar = "I am public";
    this.publicMethod = () => {
      console.log(WMGet.call(privateProp1, this), WMGet.call(privateProp2, this))
    };        
  }

  printPrivate() {
    console.log(WMGet.call(privateProp1, this));
  }
}
```

Comment: As a suggestion, you can avoid using one weak map per property by using an object as value. This way you can also reduce the number of map's `get` to one per method (e.g. `const _ = privates.get(this); console.log(_.privateProp1);`).

Comment: Yup, that's totally an option too. I mostly went with this since it maps more directly to what a user would have written when using real properties.

Comment: @loganfsmyth  `const myObj = new SomeClass(); console.log(privateProp1.get(myObj)) // "I am Private1"` that means that your property is private or not?

Comment: For that to work, the code accessing the property would need access to the WeakMap object, which would normally be scoped inside of a module and inaccessible

Answer (score 22):

For future reference of other on lookers, I'm hearing now that the recommendation is to use [WeakMaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604168/whats-the-difference-between-es6-map-and-weakmap) to hold private data.

Here is a more clear, working example:

```
function storePrivateProperties(a, b, c, d) {
  let privateData = new WeakMap;
  // unique object as key, weak map can only accept object as key, when key is no longer referened, garbage collector claims the key-value 
  let keyA = {}, keyB = {}, keyC = {}, keyD = {};

  privateData.set(keyA, a);
  privateData.set(keyB, b);
  privateData.set(keyC, c);
  privateData.set(keyD, d);

  return {
    logPrivateKey(key) {
      switch(key) {
      case "a":
        console.log(privateData.get(keyA));
        break;
      case "b":
        console.log(privateData.get(keyB));
        break;
      case "c":
        console.log(privateData.get(keyC));
        break;
      case "d":
        console.log(privateData.set(keyD));
        break;
      default:
        console.log(`There is no value for ${key}`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are your keys arrays? I know `WeakMap` will accept arrays as keys but you're instantiating 2 different arrays when you call `PRIVATE.get` and `PRIVATE.set`. Your `property` getter will return `undefined` every time.

Comment: I apologize, I've modified my example. Note that depending on the transpiler, it will not preserve block scoping with `let` declarations.

Comment: Be aware that these properties are static.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but your weakmap example is completely wrong.

Comment: Namely - You're sharing the data between all class instances and not per instance - may I at least fix it?

Comment: Indeed, the weakmap needs to be attached to a given instance. See http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/53/ for an example.

Comment: According to MDN, primitive data types such as Symbols are not allowed as a WeakMap key.
[MDN WeakMap Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap#Description)

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. (a) it doesn't run (in Babel or anywhere), (b) Instance.prop1 accesses key 'prop1', not prop1, (c) the last line cannot access prop1 because it is not in scope, (d) the last line cannot access Something because it is not in scope, (e) you cannot use a Symbol as a key on a WeakMap, and (f) the WeakMap is global, causing private variables of different instances to clobber each other.

Comment: I've corrected the example above to (a) demonstrate the usage correctly (b) work when copying and pasting anywhere. @twhb regarding (f) The previous example used block scoping, which kept the WeakMap scoped within the block, unfortunately it seems that in V8 that the class could not also escape block scoping.

Answer (score 12):

Depends on [whom you ask](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?do=search&id=class) :-)

No `private` property modifier is included in the [*Maximally minimal classes* proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes) which seems to have made it into the [current draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions).

However, there might be [support for](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:syntactic_support_for_private_names) [*private names*](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:private_names), which does allow private properties - and they probably could be used in class definitions as well.

Comment: It's _highly_ unlikely that private names will make it into ES6, though they're thinking of some form of private thing for ES7.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy both private names and unique string values have been superseded by Symbols from what I understand.

Comment: Yeah, it probably will become Symbols. However, afaik the "symbols" currently contained in the spec are only used to describe internal properties like [[prototype]], and there is no way to create and use them in user code. Do you know some docs?

Comment: I just realized that modules can be used to set privacy. Combined with Symbols that might be all you'd ever need ...?

Comment: They are in the latest spec, you can find them on Jason's copy

Comment: @d13 How would you do it. Could you link a small example snippet?

Comment: @trusktr: For modules, just export any property that you want to be public. The other properties are private by default. http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html. I was wrong about using Symbols for privacy.

Comment: @d13 One of the issues with private variables inside a module is that they can't be extended by inheriting classes, as far as I know. I still wonder if there's a way to make variables that a class can inherit and use internally, but that aren't available externally (i.e. "protected" one might say).

Comment: This seems crazy to me. If I have to add `var sym = Symbol();` I need to put my whole module/file in a closure, otherwise `sym` exists globally -- not so ECMA6-esque! Not to mention, `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`. See http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ecmascript-6-power-tutorial-class-and-inheritance--cms-24117

Comment: @Cody: Your whole *module* code does have its own scope in ES6 anyway, no need for an IEFE. And yes, symbols are purposed for uniqueness (collision-avoidance), not privacy.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. So you're saying I can avoid globals/closures with something like `class C { var sym = Symbol(); constructor () {...} ... }` ? Obviously, I'm totally new to the ECMA 6 standards -- I appreciate all your help :) Also, it looks like Ceane Lamerez's answer has everything in a just a block (`{}`) -- guess that's legal syntax, aye?

Comment: No, you cannot place the symbol in your class, but you can just place it next to it - variables declared in module scopes are not global.

Answer (score 10):

Using ES6 modules (initially proposed by @d13) works well for me. It doesn't mimic private properties perfectly, but at least you can be confident that properties that should be private won't leak outside of your class. Here's an example:

#### something.js

```
let _message = null;
const _greet = name => {
  console.log('Hello ' + name);
};

export default class Something {
  constructor(message) {
    _message = message;
  }

  say() {
    console.log(_message);
    _greet('Bob');
  }
};
```

Then the consuming code can look like this:

```
import Something from './something.js';

const something = new Something('Sunny day!');
something.say();
something._message; // undefined
something._greet(); // exception
```

#### Update (Important):

As @DanyalAytekin outlined in the comments, these private properties are static, so therefore global in scope.  They will work well when working with Singletons, but care must be taken for Transient objects.  Extending the example above:

```
import Something from './something.js';
import Something2 from './something.js';

const a = new Something('a');
a.say(); // a

const b = new Something('b');
b.say(); // b

const c = new Something2('c');
c.say(); // c

a.say(); // c
b.say(); // c
c.say(); // c
```

Comment: Good for `private static`.

Comment: @DanyalAytekin: that's a very good point. These private properties are static so global in scope. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The more I learn about functional programming (especially Elm and Haskell) the more I believe that JS programmers would benefit from a module-based approach to "modularity" rather than an OOP class-based one. If we think of ES6 modules as the foundations for building applications, and forget about classes entirely, I believe we may end up with much better applications overall. Could any experienced Elm or Haskell users comment on this approach?

Comment: In the update, the second `a.say(); // a` should be `b.say(); // b`

Comment: tried `let _message = null` way, not so cool, when call constructor multiple times, it mess up.

Comment: @Littlee You're right. Please see my update in the answer. This technique is really only acceptable for singletons.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes - you can create encapsulated property**, but it's not been done with access modifiers (public|private) at least not with ES6.

Here is a simple example how it can be done with ES6:

1 Create class using [class](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions) word

2 Inside it's constructor declare block-scoped variable using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Block_scope_with_let) OR [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) reserved words -> since they are block-scope they cannot be accessed from outside (encapsulated)

3 To allow some access control (setters|getters) to those variables you can declare instance method inside it's constructor using: `this.methodName=function(){}` syntax

```
"use strict";
    class Something{
        constructor(){
            //private property
            let property="test";
            //private final (immutable) property
            const property2="test2";
            //public getter
            this.getProperty2=function(){
                return property2;
            }
            //public getter
            this.getProperty=function(){
                return property;
            }
            //public setter
            this.setProperty=function(prop){
                property=prop;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now lets check it:

```
var s=new Something();
    console.log(typeof s.property);//undefined 
    s.setProperty("another");//set to encapsulated `property`
    console.log(s.getProperty());//get encapsulated `property` value
    console.log(s.getProperty2());//get encapsulated immutable `property2` value
```

Comment: This is (for now) the only one solution to this problem despite the fact that all methods declared in the constructor are redeclared for each instance of the class. This is pretty a bad idea regarding performance and memory usage. Class methods should be declared outside of the constructor scope.

Comment: @Freezystem First: **First** those are instance methods (not Class methods). **Second** OP question was: _ How can I prevent access to instance.property?_ and my answer is: _an example of how..._ **Third** if you have any better idea - let's hear it

Comment: I was not saying you were wrong, I said that your solution was the best compromise to achieve private variable despite the fact that a copy of each instance methods is created each time you call `new Something();` because your methods are declared in the constructor to have access to these private variables. That may cause a lot of memory consumption if you create a lot of instance of your class, so performance issues. Methods should have been declared outside of constructor scope. My comment was more an explanation of your solution drawbacks than a criticism.

Comment: But isn't it bad practice do define your entire class inside the constructor? Aren't we just "hacking" javascript now? Just look at any other OOP programming language, and you'll see that the constructor is not meant to define a class.

Comment: @Kokodoko I'm guessing that by _OOP languages_ you meant _Class-based_  languages (Java, C#, etc...) where you use access modifiers to achieve properties encapsulation. And Yes you can say it's kind of hacky way, also as you can see in my answer (and comments above), the idea was to give an example of how to achieve properties encapsulation using ES6 where access modifiers as in Java or C# are unavailable.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, and your solution works! I'm just saying that in general I am surprised that ES6 added a 'class' keyword, but removed the elegant solution of working with var and this, to achieve encapsulation.

Answer (score 9):

Completing @d13 and the comments by @johnny-oshika and @DanyalAytekin:

I guess in the example provided by @johnny-oshika we could use normal functions instead of arrow functions and then `.bind` them with the current object plus a `_privates` object as a curried parameter:

**something.js**

```
function _greet(_privates) {
  return 'Hello ' + _privates.message;
}

function _updateMessage(_privates, newMessage) {
  _privates.message = newMessage;
}

export default class Something {
  constructor(message) {
    const _privates = {
      message
    };

    this.say = _greet.bind(this, _privates);
    this.updateMessage = _updateMessage.bind(this, _privates);
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import Something from './something.js';

const something = new Something('Sunny day!');

const message1 = something.say();
something.updateMessage('Cloudy day!');
const message2 = something.say();

console.log(message1 === 'Hello Sunny day!');  // true
console.log(message2 === 'Hello Cloudy day!');  // true

// the followings are not public
console.log(something._greet === undefined);  // true
console.log(something._privates === undefined);  // true
console.log(something._updateMessage === undefined);  // true

// another instance which doesn't share the _privates
const something2 = new Something('another Sunny day!');

const message3 = something2.say();

console.log(message3 === 'Hello another Sunny day!'); // true
```

**Benefits I can think of:**

- we can have private methods (`_greet` and `_updateMessage` act like private methods as long as we don't `export` the references)
- although they're not on the prototype, the above mentioned methods will save memory because the instances are created once, outside the class (as opposed to defining them in the constructor)
- we don't leak any globals since we're inside a module
- we can also have private properties using the binded `_privates` object

**Some drawbacks I can think of:**

- less intuitive
- mixed usage of class syntax and old school patterns (object bindings, module/function scoped variables)
- hard bindings - we can't rebind the public methods (although we can improve this by using soft bindings (https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#softening-binding))

A running snippet can be found here: http://www.webpackbin.com/NJgI5J8lZ

Answer (score 9):

## A different approach to "private"

Instead of fighting against the fact that private visibility is currently unavailable in ES6, I decided to take a more practical approach that does just fine if your IDE supports JSDoc (e.g., Webstorm). The idea is to use the [`@private` tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-private.html). As far as development goes, the IDE will prevent you from accessing any private member from outside its class. Works pretty well for me and it's been really useful for hiding internal methods so the auto-complete feature shows me just what the class really meant to expose. Here's an example:

[image: auto-complete showing just public stuff]

Comment: The problem is, that we don't wan't to access the private variables over the Editor, we wan't to protect the private variables from outside - And that is, what public/private does. If your code is finished, you can access (and the important thinks: **override**) these variables from outside the class. Your `@private` comment can not prevent these, it's only a **Feature** for documentation-generation and you'r IDE.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. It's just that that's enough for me and may be enough for other people out there. I know it's not really making my variables private; it's only warning me not to try and access it from outside (only, of course, if my team and I are all using an IDE that supports this feature). Javascript (and other languages, like Python) was not designed with access levels in mind. People do all sorts of stuff to somehow implement that functionality, but in the end we end up just hacking the language to achieve that. I decided to go with a more "natural" approach, if you will.

Answer (score 7):

Oh, so many exotic solutions! I usually don't care about privacy so I use *"pseudo privacy"* as it's [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853642/1844247). But if do care (if there are some special requirements for that) I use something like in this example:

```
class jobImpl{
  // public
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  // public
  do(time){
    console.log(`${this.name} started at ${time}`);
    this.prepare();
    this.execute();
  }
  //public
  stop(time){
    this.finish();
    console.log(`${this.name} finished at ${time}`);
  }
  // private
  prepare(){ console.log('prepare..'); }
  // private
  execute(){ console.log('execute..'); }
  // private
  finish(){ console.log('finish..'); }
}

function Job(name){
  var impl = new jobImpl(name);
  return {
    do: time => impl.do(time),
    stop: time => impl.stop(time)
  };
}

// Test:
// create class "Job"
var j = new Job("Digging a ditch");
// call public members..
j.do("08:00am");
j.stop("06:00pm");

// try to call private members or fields..
console.log(j.name); // undefined
j.execute(); // error
```

---

Another possible implementation of function (constructor) `Job`:

```
function Job(name){
  var impl = new jobImpl(name);
  this.do = time => impl.do(time),
  this.stop = time => impl.stop(time)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**WeakMap**

- supported in IE11 (Symbols are not)
- hard-private (props using Symbols are soft-private due to `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`)
- can look really clean (unlike closures which require all props and methods in the constructor)

First, define a function to wrap WeakMap:

```
function Private() {
  const map = new WeakMap();
  return obj => {
    let props = map.get(obj);
    if (!props) {
      props = {};
      map.set(obj, props);
    }
    return props;
  };
}
```

Then, construct a reference outside your class:

```
const p = new Private();

class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    p(this).age = age; // it's easy to set a private variable
  }

  getAge() {
    return p(this).age; // and get a private variable
  }
}
```

Note: **class** isn't supported by IE11, but it looks cleaner in the example.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this post when looking for the best practice for "private data for classes".  It was mentioned that a few of the patterns would have performance issues.

I put together a few jsperf tests based on the 4 main patterns from the online book "Exploring ES6":

http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#sec_private-data-for-classes

The tests can be found here:

https://jsperf.com/private-data-for-classes

In Chrome 63.0.3239 / Mac OS X 10.11.6, the best performing patterns were "Private data via constructor environments" and "Private data via a naming convention".  For me Safari performed well for WeakMap but Chrome not so well.

I don't know the memory impact, but the pattern for "constructor environments" which some had warned would be a performance issue was very performant.

The 4 basic patterns are:

**Private data via constructor environments**

```
class Countdown {
    constructor(counter, action) {
        Object.assign(this, {
            dec() {
                if (counter < 1) return;
                counter--;
                if (counter === 0) {
                    action();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
const c = new Countdown(2, () => {});
c.dec();
c.dec();
```

**Private data via constructor environments 2**

```
class Countdown {
    constructor(counter, action) {
        this.dec = function dec() {
            if (counter < 1) return;
            counter--;
            if (counter === 0) {
                action();
            }
        }
    }
}
const c = new Countdown(2, () => {});
c.dec();
c.dec();
```

**Private data via a naming convention**

```
class Countdown {
    constructor(counter, action) {
        this._counter = counter;
        this._action = action;
    }
    dec() {
        if (this._counter < 1) return;
        this._counter--;
        if (this._counter === 0) {
            this._action();
        }
    }
}
const c = new Countdown(2, () => {});
c.dec();
c.dec();
```

**Private data via WeakMaps**

```
const _counter = new WeakMap();
const _action = new WeakMap();
class Countdown {
    constructor(counter, action) {
        _counter.set(this, counter);
        _action.set(this, action);
    }
    dec() {
        let counter = _counter.get(this);
        if (counter < 1) return;
        counter--;
        _counter.set(this, counter);
        if (counter === 0) {
            _action.get(this)();
        }
    }
}
const c = new Countdown(2, () => {});
c.dec();
c.dec();
```

**Private data via symbols**

```
const _counter = Symbol('counter');
const _action = Symbol('action');

class Countdown {
    constructor(counter, action) {
        this[_counter] = counter;
        this[_action] = action;
    }
    dec() {
        if (this[_counter] < 1) return;
        this[_counter]--;
        if (this[_counter] === 0) {
            this[_action]();
        }
    }
}
const c = new Countdown(2, () => {});
c.dec();
c.dec();
```

Answer (score 5):

I think [Benjamin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22160051/4019986) is probably the best for most cases until the language natively supports explicitly private variables.

However, if for some reason you need to prevent access with [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols), a method I've considered using is attaching a unique, non-configurable, non-enumerable, non-writable property that can be used as a property identifier to each object on construction (such as a unique `Symbol`, if you don't already have some other unique property like an `id`). Then just keep a map of each object's 'private' variables using that identifier.

```
const privateVars = {};

class Something {
    constructor(){
        Object.defineProperty(this, '_sym', {
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: Symbol()
        });

        var myPrivateVars = {
            privateProperty: "I'm hidden"
        };

        privateVars[this._sym] = myPrivateVars;

        this.property = "I'm public";
    }

    getPrivateProperty() {
        return privateVars[this._sym].privateProperty;
    }

    // A clean up method of some kind is necessary since the
    // variables won't be cleaned up from memory automatically
    // when the object is garbage collected
    destroy() {
        delete privateVars[this._sym];
    }
}

var instance = new Something();
console.log(instance.property); //=> "I'm public"
console.log(instance.privateProperty); //=> undefined
console.log(instance.getPrivateProperty()); //=> "I'm hidden"
```

The potential advantage of this approach over using a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) is [faster access time](https://jsperf.com/symbol-vs-weakmap/3) if performance becomes a concern.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't this code contain memory leaks since privateVars will still store an object's private variables even if the object is already destroyed?

Comment: @RussellSantos you are correct, assuming the objects will need to be garbage collected at some point. Thank you for pointing that out. In my example I've added a `destroy()` method which should be called by the using code whenever an object needs to be removed.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I like the proposal of the [bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) `::` and would then combine it with the solution @d13 mentioned but for now stick with @d13 's answer where you use the `export` keyword for your class and put the private functions in the module.

there is one more solution tough which hasn't been mentioned here that follows are more functional approach and would allow it to have all the private props/methods within the class.

**Private.js**

```
export const get = state => key => state[key];
export const set = state => (key,value) => { state[key] = value; }
```

---

**Test.js**

```
import { get, set } from './utils/Private'
export default class Test {
  constructor(initialState = {}) {
    const _set = this.set = set(initialState);
    const _get = this.get = get(initialState);

    this.set('privateMethod', () => _get('propValue'));
  }

  showProp() {
    return this.get('privateMethod')();
  }
}

let one = new Test({ propValue: 5});
let two = new Test({ propValue: 8});
two.showProp(); // 8
one.showProp(); // 5
```

comments on it would be appreciated.

Comment: Generally I like the approach.  Feedback: 1. you will need a different private.js module for each class to prevent clashing. 2. I dislike the potential of making the constructor really long by inline-defining each of your private methods. 3. It would be nice if all of the class methods were in one file.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is possible to get 'best of both worlds' using closures inside constructors. There are two variations:

**All data members are private**

```js
function myFunc() {
   console.log('Value of x: ' + this.x);
   this.myPrivateFunc();
}

function myPrivateFunc() {
   console.log('Enhanced value of x: ' + (this.x + 1));
}

class Test {
   constructor() {

      let internal = {
         x : 2,
      };
      
      internal.myPrivateFunc = myPrivateFunc.bind(internal);
      
      this.myFunc = myFunc.bind(internal);
   }
};
```

**Some members are private**

NOTE: This is admittedly ugly. If you know a better solution, please edit this response.

```js
function myFunc(priv, pub) {
   pub.y = 3; // The Test object now gets a member 'y' with value 3.
   console.log('Value of x: ' + priv.x);
   this.myPrivateFunc();
}

function myPrivateFunc() {
   pub.z = 5; // The Test object now gets a member 'z' with value 3.
   console.log('Enhanced value of x: ' + (priv.x + 1));
}

class Test {
   constructor() {
      
      let self = this;

      let internal = {
         x : 2,
      };
      
      internal.myPrivateFunc = myPrivateFunc.bind(null, internal, self);
      
      this.myFunc = myFunc.bind(null, internal, self);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In fact it is possible using Symbols and Proxies. You use the symbols in the class scope and set two traps in a proxy: one for the class prototype so that the Reflect.ownKeys(instance) or Object.getOwnPropertySymbols doesn't give your symbols away, the other one is for the constructor itself so when `new ClassName(attrs)` is called, the instance returned will be intercepted and have the own properties symbols blocked.
Here's the code:

```js
const Human = (function() {
  const pet = Symbol();
  const greet = Symbol();

  const Human = privatizeSymbolsInFn(function(name) {
    this.name = name; // public
    this[pet] = 'dog'; // private 
  });

  Human.prototype = privatizeSymbolsInObj({
    [greet]() { // private
      return 'Hi there!';
    },
    revealSecrets() {
      console.log(this[greet]() + ` The pet is a ${this[pet]}`);
    }
  });

  return Human;
})();

const bob = new Human('Bob');

console.assert(bob instanceof Human);
console.assert(Reflect.ownKeys(bob).length === 1) // only ['name']
console.assert(Reflect.ownKeys(Human.prototype).length === 1 ) // only ['revealSecrets']


// Setting up the traps inside proxies:
function privatizeSymbolsInObj(target) { 
  return new Proxy(target, { ownKeys: Object.getOwnPropertyNames });
}

function privatizeSymbolsInFn(Class) {
  function construct(TargetClass, argsList) {
    const instance = new TargetClass(...argsList);
    return privatizeSymbolsInObj(instance);
  }
  return new Proxy(Class, { construct });
}
```

`Reflect.ownKeys()` works like so: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObj).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(myObj))` that's why we need a trap for these objects.

Answer (score 4):

Even Typescript can't do it. From their [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html):

> When a member is marked private, it cannot be accessed from outside of its containing class. For example:
>
> ```
> class Animal {
>     private name: string;
>     constructor(theName: string) { this.name = theName; }
> }
>
> new Animal("Cat").name; // Error: 'name' is private;
> ```

But transpiled on their [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) this gives:

```
var Animal = (function () {
    function Animal(theName) {
        this.name = theName;
    }
    return Animal;
}());
console.log(new Animal("Cat").name);
```

So their "private" keyword is ineffective.

Comment: Well, it's still effective because it prevents "bad" programming, while in the IDE. It shows you which members you should and shouldn't use. I think that's the main reason for using private and public. (For example, when you compile C# to machine code, will private still be private? who knows?). When reading the other answers, it seems that using @Symbol can also make a member inaccessible. But even Symbols can still be found from the console.

Comment: Does the TypeScript error occur during the transpile of TypeScript to JavaScript?  (Like the type checking happens at transpite time.  Rather than some runtime private mechanism.)

Comment: Note that this response talks about TypeScript specific private *modifier*, but TypeScript 4.3 introduced additional support for [ECMAScript #private Class Elements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-3-beta/#ecmascript-private-class-elements) that unlike private modifier isn't just private at compile-time, but also at runtime (if compiled to >= ES 2015). I created [sample code in TypeScript playfeild](https://cutt.ly/ucbmge5) to demonstrate, that it is truly private (ESNext target works with Chrome, that has implemented support for ES private fields proposal)

Answer (score 4):

Coming very late to this party but I hit the OP question in a search so...
**Yes, you can have private properties by wrapping the class declaration in a closure**

There is an example of how I have private methods in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Whippy/pen/ZJNMeo). In the snippet below, the Subscribable class has two 'private' functions `process` and `processCallbacks`. Any properties can be added in this manner and they are kept private through the use of the closure. IMO Privacy is a rare need if concerns are well separated and Javascript does not need to become bloated by adding more syntax when a closure neatly does the job.

```
const Subscribable = (function(){

  const process = (self, eventName, args) => {
    self.processing.set(eventName, setTimeout(() => processCallbacks(self, eventName, args)))};

  const processCallbacks = (self, eventName, args) => {
    if (self.callingBack.get(eventName).length > 0){
      const [nextCallback, ...callingBack] = self.callingBack.get(eventName);
      self.callingBack.set(eventName, callingBack);
      process(self, eventName, args);
      nextCallback(...args)}
    else {
      delete self.processing.delete(eventName)}};

  return class {
    constructor(){
      this.callingBack = new Map();
      this.processing = new Map();
      this.toCallbacks = new Map()}

    subscribe(eventName, callback){
      const callbacks = this.unsubscribe(eventName, callback);
      this.toCallbacks.set(eventName,  [...callbacks, callback]);
      return () => this.unsubscribe(eventName, callback)}  // callable to unsubscribe for convenience

    unsubscribe(eventName, callback){
      let callbacks = this.toCallbacks.get(eventName) || [];
      callbacks = callbacks.filter(subscribedCallback => subscribedCallback !== callback);
      if (callbacks.length > 0) {
        this.toCallbacks.set(eventName, callbacks)}
      else {
        this.toCallbacks.delete(eventName)}
      return callbacks}

    emit(eventName, ...args){
      this.callingBack.set(eventName, this.toCallbacks.get(eventName) || []);
      if (!this.processing.has(eventName)){
        process(this, eventName, args)}}}})();
```

I like this approach because it separates concerns nicely and keeps things truly private. The only downside is the need to use 'self' (or something similar) to refer to 'this' in the private content.

Answer (score 4):

Yes totally can, and pretty easily too. This is done by exposing your private variables and functions by returning the prototype object graph in the constructor. This is nothing new, but take a bit of js foo to understand the elegance of it. This way does not use global scoped, or weakmaps. It is a form of reflection built into the language. Depending on how you leverage this; one can either force an exception which interrupts the call stack, or bury the exception as an `undefined`. This is demonstarted below, and can read more about these features [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```js
class Clazz {
  constructor() {
    var _level = 1

    function _private(x) {
      return _level * x;
    }
    return {
      level: _level,
      public: this.private,
      public2: function(x) {
        return _private(x);
      },
      public3: function(x) {
        return _private(x) * this.public(x);
      },
    };
  }

  private(x) {
    return x * x;
  }
}

var clazz = new Clazz();

console.log(clazz._level); //undefined
console.log(clazz._private); // undefined
console.log(clazz.level); // 1
console.log(clazz.public(1)); //1
console.log(clazz.public2(2)); //2
console.log(clazz.public3(3)); //27
console.log(clazz.private(0)); //error
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Something {
  constructor(){
    var _property = "test";
    Object.defineProperty(this, "property", {
        get: function(){ return _property}
    });
  }
}

var instance = new Something();
console.log(instance.property); //=> "test"
instance.property = "can read from outside, but can't write";
console.log(instance.property); //=> "test"
```

Comment: It's best to avoid code only answers. It would be better if you could explain how your code answers the OP's question

Comment: This is really how to make a readonly variable more than a private variable.  A private variable should not be accessible to the outside.  `console.log(instance.property)` should throw or give you undefined, not give you back "test".

Answer (score 3):

Another way similar to the last two posted

```
class Example {
  constructor(foo) {

    // privates
    const self = this;
    this.foo = foo;

    // public interface
    return self.public;
  }

  public = {
    // empty data
    nodata: { data: [] },
    // noop
    noop: () => {},
  }

  // everything else private
  bar = 10
}

const test = new Example('FOO');
console.log(test.foo); // undefined
console.log(test.noop); // { data: [] }
console.log(test.bar); // undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a very simple solution, just use `Object.freeze()`. Of course the problem is you can't add nothing to the object later.

```
class Cat {
    constructor(name ,age) {
        this.name = name
        this.age = age
        Object.freeze(this)
    }
}

let cat = new Cat('Garfield', 5)
cat.age = 6 // doesn't work, even throws an error in strict mode
```

Comment: this will also disable setter method like `setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }`

Answer (score 3):

Reading the previous answer i thought that this example can summarise the above solutions

```
const friend = Symbol('friend');

const ClassName = ((hidden, hiddenShared = 0) => {

    class ClassName {
        constructor(hiddenPropertyValue, prop){
            this[hidden] = hiddenPropertyValue * ++hiddenShared;
            this.prop = prop
        }

        get hidden(){
            console.log('getting hidden');
            return this[hidden];
        }

        set [friend](v){
            console.log('setting hiddenShared');
            hiddenShared = v;
        }

        get counter(){
            console.log('getting hiddenShared');
            return hiddenShared;
        }

        get privileged(){
            console.log('calling privileged method');
            return privileged.bind(this);
        }
    }

    function privileged(value){
        return this[hidden] + value;
    }

    return ClassName;
})(Symbol('hidden'), 0);

const OtherClass = (() => class OtherClass extends ClassName {
    constructor(v){
        super(v, 100);
        this[friend] = this.counter - 1;
    }
})();
```

### UPDATE

now is it possible to make true private properties and methods (at least on chrome based browsers for now).

The syntax is pretty neat

```
class MyClass {
    #privateProperty = 1
    #privateMethod() { return 2 }
    static #privateStatic = 3
    static #privateStaticMethod(){return 4}
    static get #privateStaticGetter(){return 5}

    // also using is quite straightforward
    method(){
        return (
            this.#privateMethod() +
            this.#privateProperty +
            MyClass.#privateStatic +
            MyClass.#privateStaticMethod() +
            MyClass.#privateStaticGetter
        )
    }
}

new MyClass().method()
// returns 15
```

Note that for retrieving static references you wouldn't use `this.constructor.#private`, because it would brake its subclasses. You must use a reference to the proper class in order to retrieve its static private references (that are available only inside the methods of that class), ie `MyClass.#private`.

Answer (score 3):

This code demonstrates private and public, static and non-static, instance and class-level, variables, methods, and properties.

https://codesandbox.io/s/class-demo-837bj

```js
class Animal {
    static count = 0 // class static public
    static #ClassPriVar = 3 // class static private

    constructor(kind) {
        this.kind = kind // instance public property
        Animal.count++
        let InstancePriVar = 'InstancePriVar: ' + kind // instance private constructor-var
        log(InstancePriVar)
        Animal.#ClassPriVar += 3
        this.adhoc = 'adhoc' // instance public property w/out constructor- parameter
    }

    #PawCount = 4 // instance private var

    set Paws(newPawCount) {
        // instance public prop
        this.#PawCount = newPawCount
    }

    get Paws() {
        // instance public prop
        return this.#PawCount
    }

    get GetPriVar() {
        // instance public prop
        return Animal.#ClassPriVar
    }

    static get GetPriVarStat() {
        // class public prop
        return Animal.#ClassPriVar
    }

    PrintKind() {
        // instance public method
        log('kind: ' + this.kind)
    }

    ReturnKind() {
        // instance public function
        return this.kind
    }

    /* May be unsupported

    get #PrivMeth(){  // instance private prop
        return Animal.#ClassPriVar + ' Private Method'
    }

    static get #PrivMeth(){  // class private prop
        return Animal.#ClassPriVar + ' Private Method'
    }
    */
}

function log(str) {
    console.log(str)
}

// TESTING

log(Animal.count) // static, avail w/out instance
log(Animal.GetPriVarStat) // static, avail w/out instance

let A = new Animal('Cat')
log(Animal.count + ': ' + A.kind)
log(A.GetPriVar)
A.PrintKind()
A.Paws = 6
log('Paws: ' + A.Paws)
log('ReturnKind: ' + A.ReturnKind())
log(A.adhoc)

let B = new Animal('Dog')
log(Animal.count + ': ' + B.kind)
log(B.GetPriVar)
log(A.GetPriVar) // returns same as B.GetPriVar. Acts like a class-level property, but called like an instance-level property. It's cuz non-stat fx requires instance.

log('class: ' + Animal.GetPriVarStat)

// undefined
log('instance: ' + B.GetPriVarStat) // static class fx
log(Animal.GetPriVar) // non-stat instance fx
log(A.InstancePriVar) // private
log(Animal.InstancePriVar) // private instance var
log('PawCount: ' + A.PawCount) // private. Use getter
/* log('PawCount: ' + A.#PawCount) // private. Use getter
log('PawCount: ' + Animal.#PawCount) // Instance and private. Use getter */
```

Answer (score 2):

Most answers either say it's impossible, or require you to use a WeakMap or Symbol, which are ES6 features that would probably require polyfills. There's however another way! Check out this out:

```js
// 1. Create closure
var SomeClass = function() {
  // 2. Create `key` inside a closure
  var key = {};
  // Function to create private storage
  var private = function() {
    var obj = {};
    // return Function to access private storage using `key`
    return function(testkey) {
      if(key === testkey) return obj;
      // If `key` is wrong, then storage cannot be accessed
      console.error('Cannot access private properties');
      return undefined;
    };
  };
  var SomeClass = function() {
    // 3. Create private storage
    this._ = private();
    // 4. Access private storage using the `key`
    this._(key).priv_prop = 200;
  };
  SomeClass.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log(this._(key).priv_prop); // Using property from prototype
  };
  return SomeClass;
}();

// Can access private property from within prototype
var instance = new SomeClass();
instance.test(); // `200` logged

// Cannot access private property from outside of the closure
var wrong_key = {};
instance._(wrong_key); // undefined; error logged
```

I call this method **accessor pattern**. The essential idea is that we have a *closure*, a *key* inside the closure, and we create a *private object* (in the constructor) that can only be accessed if you have the *key*.

If you are interested, you can read more about this in [my article](https://medium.com/@weberino/you-can-create-truly-private-properties-in-js-without-es6-7d770f55fbc3). Using this method, you can create per object properties that cannot be accessed outside of the closure. Therefore, you can use them in constructor or prototype, but not anywhere else. I haven't seen this method used anywhere, but I think it's really powerful.

Comment: The question was about how to achieve this in ES6 classes.

Comment: You can use the exact same method in ES6 classes. ES6 classes is mainly just sugar on top of functions like I presented in my example. It's quite possible that the original poster is using a transpiler, in which case WeakMaps or Symbols will still require polyfills. My answer is valid regardless.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39222779/460084) for a a clean & simple 'class' solution with a private and public interface and support for composition

Answer (score 2):

Actually it **is** possible.
1. First, create the class and in the constructor return the called `_public` function.
2. In the called `_public` function pass the `this` reference *(to get the access to all private methods and props)*, and all arguments from `constructor` *(that will be passed in `new Names()`)*
3. In the `_public` function scope there is also the `Names` class with the access to `this` (_this) reference of the private `Names` class

```
class Names {
  constructor() {
    this.privateProperty = 'John';
    return _public(this, arguments);
  }
  privateMethod() { }
}

const names = new Names(1,2,3);
console.log(names.somePublicMethod); //[Function]
console.log(names.publicProperty); //'Jasmine'
console.log(names.privateMethod); //undefined
console.log(names.privateProperty); //undefind

function _public(_this, _arguments) {
  class Names {
    constructor() {
      this.publicProperty = 'Jasmine';
      _this.privateProperty; //"John";
      _this.privateMethod; //[Function]
    }

    somePublicMethod() {
      _this.privateProperty; //"John";
      _this.privateMethod; //[Function]
    }

  }
  return new Names(..._arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this pattern and it's always worked for me

```js
class Test {
    constructor(data) {
        class Public {
            constructor(prv) {

                // public function (must be in constructor on order to access "prv" variable)
                connectToDb(ip) {
                    prv._db(ip, prv._err);
                } 
            }

            // public function w/o access to "prv" variable
            log() {
                console.log("I'm logging");
            }
        }

        // private variables
        this._data = data;
        this._err = function(ip) {
            console.log("could not connect to "+ip);
        }
    }

    // private function
    _db(ip, err) {
        if(!!ip) {
      console.log("connected to "+ip+", sending data '"+this.data+"'");
   return true;
  }
        else err(ip);
    }
}



var test = new Test(10),
  ip = "185.167.210.49";
test.connectToDb(ip); // true
test.log(); // I'm logging
test._err(ip); // undefined
test._db(ip, function() { console.log("You have got hacked!"); }); // undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-members

This package will save the members by instance.

```
const pvt = require('private-members');
const _ = pvt();

let Exemplo = (function () {    
    function Exemplo() {
        _(this).msg = "Minha Mensagem";
    }

    _().mensagem = function() {
        return _(this).msg;
    }

    Exemplo.prototype.showMsg = function () {
        let msg = _(this).mensagem();
        console.log(msg);
    };

    return Exemplo;
})();

module.exports = Exemplo;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have private methods in classes using `WeakMap`.

[According to MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections#WeakMap_object):

> The WeakMap object is a collection of key/value pairs in which the keys are objects only and the values can be arbitrary values.
>
> The object references in the keys are held weakly, meaning that they are a target of garbage collection (GC) if there is no other reference to the object anymore.

And this is an example of creating [`Queue` data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) with a private member `_items` which holds an array.

```
const _items = new WeakMap();

class Queue {    
    constructor() {
        _items.set(this, []);
    }

    enqueue( item) {
        _items.get(this).push(item);
    }    

    get count() {
        return _items.get(this).length;        
    }

    peek() {
        const anArray = _items.get(this);
        if( anArray.length == 0)
            throw new Error('There are no items in array!');

        if( anArray.length > 0)
            return anArray[0];
    }

    dequeue() {        
        const anArray = _items.get(this);
        if( anArray.length == 0)
            throw new Error('There are no items in array!');

        if( anArray.length > 0)
            return anArray.splice(0, 1)[0];
    }    
}
```

An example of using:

```
const c = new Queue();
c.enqueue("one");
c.enqueue("two");
c.enqueue("three");
c.enqueue("four");
c.enqueue("five");
console.log(c);
```

Private member `_items` is hided and cannot be seen in properties or methods of an `Queue` object:

[image]

However, private member `_items`  in the `Queue` object can be reached using this way:

```
const anArray = _items.get(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the **myThing** variable is private and is part of the closure:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {

    var myThing = "Hello World";

    return {
      thing: myThing,
      sayThing: this.sayThing
    }
  }

  sayThing() {
    console.log(this.thing);
  }
}

var person = new Person();

console.log(person);
```

Comment: `person.thing = "Crack"; console.log(person);` Result will be `{thing: "Crack", sayThing: ƒ}`. This one is not private.

Comment: constructor should have no return statement

Answer (score 1):

I realize there are dozens of answers here. I want to share my solution, which ensures true private variables in ES6 classes and in older JS.

```
var MyClass = (function() {
    var $ = new WeakMap();
    function priv(self) {
       var r = $.get(self);
       if (!r) $.set(self, r={});
       return r;
    }

    return class { /* use priv(this).prop inside your class */ } 
}();
```

Privacy is ensured by the fact that the outside world don't get access to $.

When the instance goes away, the WeakMap will release the data.

This definitely works in plain Javascript, and I believe they work in ES6 classes but I haven't tested that $ will be available inside the scope of member methods.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given you can also use a Proxy to create "private properties" by making only the proxy available to public code. The instance is only available to the constructor, bound methods and the Proxy itself as the `receiver`.

This has some advantages over using Symbols and WeakMaps.

- Symbols are enumerable and can be captured with a Proxy.
- WeakMaps fail when the instance is proxied as the `instance !== new Proxy(instance)`

**Fail of WeakMap eg.**

```
const map = new WeakMap()

const instance = new SomeClass()
map.set(instance, 'foo')
// somewhere along the way in 3rd party code
const proxy = new Proxy(instance, {})
assert(map.set(instance) === map.get(proxy)) // fail
const proxy2 = new Proxy(proxy, {})
// more headache
```

**Using a proxy to decorate an instance with private props validation**

```
getProxy = (instance) => new Proxy(instance, {

    get: (target, name, receiver) => {
        console.log('get', { target, name, receiver })
        if (name[0] === '_') throw new Error('Cannot access private property ' + name)
        return Reflect.get(target, name, receiver) 
    },
    set: (target, name, value, receiver) => {
        console.log('set', { target, name, value, receiver })
        if (name[0] === '_') throw new Error('Cannot set private property ' + name)
        return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver) 
    }
    
})


class PublicClass {

    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, '_privateProp', { enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: false })
        return getProxy(this) // can be moved out as a decorator
    }

    getPrivatePropFail() {
        return this._privateProp // fail
    }

    getPrivateProp = () => {
        return this._privateProp // ok
    }

    setPrivateProp = (value) => {
        return this._privateProp = value // ok
    }

}


pub = new PublicClass()

try {
    console.log('get pub._privateProp', pub._privateProp)
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e) 
}
try {
    console.log('set pub._privateProp', pub._privateProp = 'you fail')
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e) 
}
pub.setPrivateProp('you ok')
console.log('pub.getPrivateProp()', pub.getPrivateProp())
console.log('pub', Object.keys(pub))
```

**The advantages of this approach**

- The private property access validation is decorated (optional) onto the instance.
- The private properties are inspectable in the console, debuggers and testing environment and simple properties (no symbols or maps)
- You control the validation and error handling

**The drawbacks**

- The proxy adds overhead and a level of abstraction
- Debugging will show the Proxy() wrapping the object
- Methods accessing private props need to be arrow functions
- You can leak the private props when unintentionally exposing the instance eg. adding a method `getSelf = () => this`

**Notes:**

Given the overhead this method could be used in scenarios where property encapsulation and clarity of debugging outweighs the overhead. For example when populating Models from storage. eg. `model.setJSON(json)` would ensure no private props are mangled.

This method can be further adapted to provide better encapsulation by using a WeakMap together with the Proxy to ensure "private" properties are not visible yet allow accessing the WeakMap with the same instance at every scope. This however sacrifices readability and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

As per ES2022, We can add private properties and methods in our JavaScript class.

we can define private fields by pre-pending `#` to their names.

**Demo :**

```js
class Something {
  #property = "test"; // By adding # followed with the property name we are making it private.
}

var instance = new Something();

console.log(instance.#property); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#property' must be declared in an enclosing class
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know there is no native support for private properties with ES6 classes.

Below is just what I use (might be helpful). Basically I'm wrapping a class inside the factory.

```
function Animal(name) {
    const privateData = 'NO experiments on animals have been done!';

    class Animal {
        constructor(_name) {
            this.name = _name;
        }
        getName() {
            return this.name
        }
        getDisclamer() {
            return `${privateData} Including ${this.name}`
        }
    }
    return new Animal(name)
}
```

I'm a beginner so happy to hear if this is a bad approach.

Comment: Something to consider: what happens if try to you extend `Animal`?

Comment: This looks like a great approach, but it had gotten downvoted... ?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a module that helps you use the access restriction in the 
JavaScript class called Capsulable. (Private & Protected Static)

If you're interested, check out my package below.
https://github.com/hmmhmmhm/capsulable

```
const Capsulable = require('capsulable')
const Field = Capsulable()

class A {
    constructor(_field){
        // Configure data fields.
        Field(this, _field)

        // The code below provides access to
        // the data fields when creating
        // functions within the class.
        Field(this).private
        Field(this).protected
        Field(this).protectedStatic
    }
}

module.exports = A
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that works woo and it pretty simple... although performance is prob not the pest... but it works and works well.

The trick is that until private properties and functions are established and standardized/adopted work arounds are required and this is another workaround...

```
class ClassPrivateProperties {
    constructor(instance) {
        const $this = instance;
        let properties = {};
        this.prop = (key, value = undefined) => {
            if (!value) {
                return properties[key];
            } else {
                properties[key] = value;
            }
        };
        this.clear = instance => {
            if ($this === instance) {
                properties = {};
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample usage that can be what ever (also if you use the above feel free to make it better)

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this._privateProps = new ClassPrivateProperties(this);
    }
    property(key, value = undefined) {
        if (!value) {
            return this._privateProps.prop(key);
        } else {
            this._privateProps.prop(key, value);
        }
    }
    clear() { return this._privateProps.clear(this); }
}
const test = new test;
test.property('myKey','some value here');
console.log(test.property('myKey'));
```

Like I mentioned that this prob not the best of the best but it works and makes properties truly private.

Answer (score 0):

we can emulate a private property of a class using getter and setter.

## eg 1

```
class FootballClub {
    constructor (cname, cstadium, ccurrentmanager) {
        this.name = cname;
        this._stadium  = cstadium;  //  we will treat this prop as private and give getter and setter for this.
        this.currmanager = ccurrentmanager;
    }

    get stadium( ) {
        return this._stadium.toUpperCase();
    }

}

let club = new FootballClub("Arsenal", "Emirates" , "Arteta")
console.log(club);
//FootballClub {
//    name: 'Arsenal',
//    _stadium: 'Emirates',
//    currmanager: 'Arteta'
//  }
console.log( club.stadium ); // EMIRATES
club.stadium = "Highbury"; // TypeError: Cannot set property stadium of #<FootballClub> which has only a getter
```

In the above example we have not given a setter method for *stadium* and thus we are not able to set a new value for this. In the next eg a setter is added for *stadium*

## eg 2

```
class FootballClub {
    constructor (cname, cstadium, ccurrentmanager) {
        this.name = cname;
        this._stadium  = cstadium;  //  we will treat this prop as private and give getter and setter for this.
        this.currmanager = ccurrentmanager;
    }

    get stadium( ) {
        return this._stadium.toUpperCase();
    }

    set stadium(val) {
       this._stadium = val;
    }
}

let club = new FootballClub("Arsenal", "Emirates" , "Arteta")
console.log(club.stadium); // EMIRATES
club.stadium = "Emirates Stadium";
console.log(club.stadium); // EMIRATES STADIUM
```