# are there no private vars in ecma6 classes?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, private, getter

I feel kind of stupid about this, but from what I've searched and read I understand that there is no way to create a truely private var in ecma6 classes.
am I correct?

this is an examplee of a getter function in emca5, is there anyway to do this in ecma6-classes?

```
function foo() {
var me="foo";
    this.getPrivate() {
       return me
    }
}
var new_foo = new foo()
console.log( new_foo.me) //return undefined
console.log( new_foo.getPrivate()) //return "foo"
```

Comment: sorry, I've re-edited it.
the question stays the same, how to do this in ecma6?

Comment: Yes, of course you can do the same thing in ES6 classes. Just move the contents of your `foo` function into the `class foo { constructor() … }`, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34871822/1048572).

Comment: but if a new function is added to the class it will not see the vars inside the constructor.

Comment: Just like `foo.protoype` methods were not able to in the ES5 snippet. Nothing changes in that regard.

Comment: _"but if a new function is added to the class it will not see the vars inside the constructor"_ But it will see `getPrivate`. It's preferable to define "real"  getters / setters.