# How to keep injected dependencies private in AngularJS Controllers with ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

I know that my question is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes), but I wonder if there is an AngularJS specific way to address this issue.

Here is the deal:

I'm using ES6 Class and `ControllerAs` in my Angular directives, so controllers are declared like so:

```js
class myCtrl {
  constructor ( $log ) {
    'ngInject';

    // Dependency Injections
    var privateLog  = $log;      // Private but scoped to constructor
    this.publicLog  = $log;      // Public

    // Default attributes
    this.foo = 'bar';

    this.publicLog.log('it works in constructor');  // logs 'it works in constructor'
    privateLog.log('it works in constructor');      // logs 'it works in constructor'
  }

  logSomething () {
    this.publicLog.log('it works in class method'); // logs 'it works in class method'
    try {
      privateLog.log('it works in class method');
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e);                               // Uncaught ReferenceError: privateLog is not defined
    }
  }
}

var test = new myCtrl();

test.logSomething();
test.publicLog.log('is public');      // logs 'is public' 
try {
  test.privateLog.log('is private');
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(e);                     // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
}
```

The thing is that I want to have access to my dependency injections in all classe methods,
but I don't want them to be reachable publicly from the outside.

Moreover I don't want to declare my methods in the constructor as I don't want them to be redeclared for each instance.

Is there a proper way to do this or am I missing something ?

[Here is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/freezystem/q4pj6m39/embedded/js/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep injectables private, use classical angular controller structure, like this

```
function MyCtrl($log) {
   'ngInject';
   this.logSomething = function(message) {
       $log(message);
   }
}
```

Now actual `$log` is hidden in closure, but `logSomething` publicly available for templates.

**UPD.** If you want to keep using ES6 classes for some reason, you can try to use any existing methods to make some class member as private. There is [a review](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533611/1297743) of possible ways to do it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I think I'll be force to do, but I was interested in finding a workaround I could use to make this work with ES6 Class. =(