# Setting a namespace variable to "private"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a namespace and are wondering how I can restrict accessibility to a namespace variable so that it only can be accessed from inside the namespace.

In my sample code I want **PrivateExec** to be `private` and not accessible outside the namespace.

```
var demo = {
    a: "demo",
    b: {
        PrivateExec: function () {
            //execute
        },
        ExecA: function () {
            PrivateExec();
        },
        ExecB: function () {
            PrivateExec();
        }
    }
}

demo.ExecA(); //success
demo.PrivateExec(); //fails because of private
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Private properties in JavaScript ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes)

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns" (https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) for pre-ES6. See the "Module" pattern for an example of private methods.

Comment: *Why* does it have to be private?

Comment: With how you are doing it, not going to happen.

Answer (score -2):

Try NOT using this code: Your variable should be private !

```
var value = Symbol();
class MyClass {
    constructor(){
        this[value] = "this is a test string";
    }
}

var call = new MyClass();

console.log(call.value); // should be undefined
```

Comment: 1. - 2. It is kind of private, sure. Yeah `call.value` is undefined. Do you know why? - BECAUSE ITS PRIVATE! @JaredSmith

Comment: `call[value]` will still give you the string. `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(call)` will still get you the string. Not private.

Comment: I have to agree with @JaredSmith here. The only way to have proper private stuff (in the sense "not accessible from the outside world") is to play with scopes.

Comment: You can not create PRIVATE variables. You have to use scopes like sp00m mentioned. But I've edited my answer @JaredSmith :)

Comment: @sp00m eh, native modules get you there, but that limits your clients.

Comment: @JaredSmith Good old IIFE FTW!