# How can I write a closure function in getter in ES6 ?

Tags: ecmascript-6, closures

In ES5, I can write it like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.value = (function() {
    var privateVariable = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++privateVariable;
    };
})();
```

But in ES6, how can I do it ?

```
class MyClass {
    get value() {
        // return ??
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Private properties in JavaScript ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct counterpart, which is not idiomatic to ES6 classes:

```
class MyClass {}
MyClass.prototype.value = (() => {
    let privateVariable = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++privateVariable;
    };
})();
```

There are no practical reasons to make `privateVariable` completely unavailable from the outer scope, especially since it doesn't play well with ES6 classes. This cannot be considered a proper encapsulation because `privateVariable` isn't available for reflection; it cannot act as protected member as well.

There can be private member that stores a value:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
         this._value = 0;
    }

    value() {
        return ++this._value;
    }
}
```

It could be a symbol but this doesn't make class design more secure, just introduces additional complications when a class is inherited in another module:

```
// should be carried around everywhere to make the class extendable
export const VALUE = Symbol('value');

class MyClass {
    constructor() {
         this[VALUE] = 0;
    }

    value() {
        return ++this[VALUE];
    }
}
```

Note that `get value() {}` is not same thing as `value() {}`.

One of TypeScript (which is a superset of ECMAScript) benefits is the encapsulation that is enforced at compilation time.

Comment: In fact, I want to write a function like this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L195-L205.

Comment: @user2331095 You can write it the way you like. I'm just saying that it's not idiomatic and you won't see this in well-written ES6 OO code, because this approach doesn't have obvious advantages, while, on the contrary, the disadvantages are obvious. A lot of good coding habits tend to become obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to the ES5

```
function MyClass() {}
var privateVariable = 0;
MyClass.prototype = {
    get value() {
        return ++privateVariable;
    }
};
```

in ES6 `class` syntax would be

```
let privateVariable = 0;
class MyClass {
    get value() {
        return ++privateVariable;
    }
}
```

Whether you put all that in an IEFE or module or whatnot for local scope doesn't matter, it's the same.