# Typescript access modifiers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning access modifiers in typescript, I have the following class .

```
 export class Person {
      private get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + '' + this.lastname;
      }
      constructor(public firstName, public lastname) {

      }
    }
    const name = new Person('jim', 'jonson');
    alert(name.fullName);
```

When I hover on full name *Intellisense* gives me the following error

> Property 'fullName' is private and only accessible within class 'Person'.

Can somebody explain me why full name is displayed on my browser?

Comment: TypeScript errors do not prevent compilation into JavaScript, so they are effectively warnings of incorrect usage that could potentially lead to unintended behavior in the resulting JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for explanation bro apreaciate so for what your saying , meaning Js lacks privacy at all?

Comment: `Js lacks privacy at all` [Javascript has privacy, it's all about implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes).  That being said, the Access Modifiers you're specifying are not *Javascript* they are *Typescript*.. huge difference.

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks for the link now understand it , i was confused little bit )  u can put as answer I will accept it .

Comment: What IDE are you using? The IDE intellisense can display that as info, but if it marks as error than the IDE has a bug.

Comment: visual code, I tried even changing to this `alert(name['fullName']);` also works so its not about ide read the link provided by another fella above , there is complete expalantion about this.

Comment: why is your getter *private* but the attribute it encapsulates is *public*? That's backwards.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga codes is okay nothing wrong I was just wondering about the privacy of js whatsover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access modifiers in typescript is typescript feature rather than javascript feature.

So when you compile .ts to .js this kind of feature is over-ridden; like interfaces.

Maybe in future releases, JavaScript will have access modifiers .

During compilation you will get the error

> Property 'fullName' is private and only accessible within class
>   'Person'.

You can change this compiler option in tsconfig.ts file

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true
}
```

This will stop typescript compiler if there is an error.

Happy Coding;