# How can I use a private instance method in my Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am refactoring an existing Chrome Packaged App and it now uses [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). I want to make some of the methods of the class private. The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_instance_methods) has an example for this:

```
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 'hello world';
  }

  getPrivateMessage() {
      return #privateMethod();
  }
}

const instance = new ClassWithPrivateMethod();
console.log(instance.getPrivateMessage());
// expected output: "hello worl​d"
```

When wrap this example code into a Chrome Packaged App the app refuses to run, I instead see:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('

This is reported against line 2: `#privateMethod(){`

However, if I go to an [earlier example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_instance_fields) that uses private instance fields:

```
class ClassWithPrivateField {
  #privateField;

  constructor() {
    this.#privateField = 42;
    this.#randomField = 666; # Syntax error
  }
}

const instance = new ClassWithPrivateField();
instance.#privateField === 42; // Syntax error
```

When wrapped as a Chrome Packaged App this code snippit does produce the expected result.

Therefore my questions are:

- Am I supposed to be able to use private instance methods in my Chrome Packaged Apps?
- Is this a bug (I think it is so I posted [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1024819)) or is this designed/desired behaviour?
- Has anybody else been able to use private instance methods in their development of Chrome Packaged Apps?
- Is there a different technique I can use to make certain methods of a class private?

**UPDATE 2019-11-14:**

I got a workaround but not one that I'm particularly happy with:

```
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod

  constructor(){
      this.#privateMethod = function(){
          return 'hello world';
      };
  }

  getPrivateMessage() {
      return this.#privateMethod();
  }
}
const instance = new ClassWithPrivateMethod();
console.log(instance.getPrivateMessage());
```

By making `#privateMethod` a private field of the class and then using the constructor to assign it a function I can create a private method however this means declaring all of my function code inside the constructor which would make it messy and difficult for any future developers to read.

Comment: Please check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Not specific to Chrome apps/extensions as they use the same JavaScript syntax.

Comment: BTW you can use `get privateMessage()` instead, see [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods).