# What javascript syntax is used like the {get;set} syntax in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#

As a developer in C#, I am shifting to learning JavaScript. Here is a piece of code in C#:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

How would I transform this code(getters/setters) to JavaScript?

Comment: I would start with the documentation, and go from there.  [Getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [Setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  #name = "initial";
  get name() { return this.#name; };
  set name(value) { this.#name = value; };
```

That would be the closest Javascript, using [private class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes) and [class getter / setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype%20methods).