# How to go through an object to modify a class

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

If given an object as a parameter to modify a created `ExcelFile` (using *Class*), how can I go through that object to find what parameter needs to be modified and then changed in the `ExcelFile`?

For example if I call `modify({date: 12/31/2020})` I want it to update the date to 12/31/2020, however if I give it  `modify({date: '12/31/2020', duration: '60 minutes'})` it would update both date and duration.

My thinking was below but it is not identifying date...

```
class ExcelFile{
    constructor(arr){
        this.date = arr[0];
        this.duration = arr[1];
    }
    modify(obj){
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (obj[key] === "date") {
                 this.date = obj[date];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "class" isn't the right term - in JS it's called "property". Object property

Comment: Do you *always* want to **only** update the `date` property and no other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, just change the properties directly using `this[key]`:

```js
class ExcelFile{
    constructor(arr){
        this.date = arr[0];
        this.duration = arr[1];
    }
    modify(obj){
        for (let key in obj) {
            this[key] = obj[key]
        }
    }
}

let file = new ExcelFile(["01/01/2020", "30 minutes"])
console.log(file)

file.modify({ date: "02/02/2020" })
console.log(file)

file.modify({ date: '12/31/2020', duration: '60 minutes' })
console.log(file)

// You can also add new properties:
file.modify({ date: '12/01/2005', size: "100 Mb" })
console.log(file)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for answering and breaking it out in the code!

Comment: @JordanRaleigh Do accept the answer if it helped by clicking the grey tick mark next to it :)

Comment: Done, first question. Thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to modify the date property of your `ExcelFile` instance then you do not need to iterate the Object you are sending to the `modify` method, but you can directly access the `date` property of the argument via [destructuring](https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-function-arguments)

```js
class ExcelFile{
    constructor(arr){
        this.date = arr[0];
        this.duration = arr[1];
    }
    modify({date, duration}){
        this.date = date || this.date
        this.duration = duration || this.duration
    }
}

const file = new ExcelFile(["01/01/2020", "30 minutes"])
console.log(file)

file.modify({ date:"NEW DATE! 10/10/3000" })
console.log(file)

file.modify({ date:"foo", duration:"bar", unwanted:"baz" })
console.log(file)
```

Comment: OP clearly states that it can also be a `duration` property

Comment: Although I was thinking, this is a loosely typed language, isn't it just possible to do `file.date = "somevalue"` without any class method?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - your question might be related to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22156326/104380)