# Force the use of setters instead of straight assignments in a JS ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a CameraBuilder class that looks like this:

```
class CameraBuilder {
    constructor() {
        if (arguments.length) {
            throw new Error('[CameraBuilder constructor ERROR] class constructor does not accept parameters.');
        }
        this.camera = {};
    }

    withFarmLabel(farmLabel) {
        this.camera.farm_label = farmLabel;
        return this;
    }

    // more methods here

    build() {
        const missingProps = [];
        if (!this.camera.farm_label) {
            missingProps.push('\nMissing farm_label property. Use the withFarmLabel method in order to assign it.');
        }
        
        // more validations like the one above here

        if (missingProps.length) {
            const errorMsg = missingProps.join('');
            throw new Error(`[CameraBuilder build ERROR] ${errorMsg}`);
        }

        return this.camera;
    }
}
```

Since most of my validations are on the `build()` method and there are some business logic on some of these methods associated with how the user is building an instance of CameraBuilder, I wouldn't want anyone assigning `cameraBuilderObj.camera` directly. Is there any way I can enforce the use of the Class methods in order to assign properties to the Camera object?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to wait for ES10 and the proposed private fields using `#`. Only other real option is to use the functionality for private fields already implemented in TypeScript.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237988/1441

Answer (score 3):

You could make the `camera` property private by putting `#` in front of it, ensuring that only `CameraBuilder`'s internals can reference it:

```js
class CameraBuilder {
    #camera = {};
    constructor() {
        if (arguments.length) {
            throw new Error('[CameraBuilder constructor ERROR] class constructor does not accept parameters.');
        }
    }

    withFarmLabel(farmLabel) {
        this.#camera.farm_label = farmLabel;
        return this;
    }

    // more methods here

    build() {
        const missingProps = [];
        if (!this.#camera.farm_label) {
            missingProps.push('\nMissing farm_label property. Use the withFarmLabel method in order to assign it.');
        }
        
        // more validations like the one above here

        if (missingProps.length) {
            const errorMsg = missingProps.join('');
            throw new Error(`[CameraBuilder build ERROR] ${errorMsg}`);
        }

        return this.#camera;
    }
}

const c = new CameraBuilder();
c.withFarmLabel('label');
console.log(c.camera);
console.log(c.build().farm_label);
```

Comment: this seems amazing! do you know if that's available in newer NodeJS releases?

Comment: Yes, they're available in Node 12+.

Answer (score 1):

[CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016300/636077) probably makes more sense--don't expose it in the first place--but if for some reason you didn't want to go that route (or if you're in an environment where [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) aren't supported) you could define [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) on it, so that direct assignments go through your function.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this._bar = 'baz';
  }

  set bar (value) {
    this._bar = value;
    console.log('do whatever you want to do here.');
  }
}

const f = new Foo();
f.bar = 'hey'; // direct assignment invokes the setter
```

Comment: Since my setter sets values for properties for an object of the main class (CameraBuilder.camera), can I still take advantage of this? I mean, how this would stop the user from doing `cameraBuilderObj.camera.blabla = 'bleble'`? For what I understood, this only applies to the Class properties, right?

Comment: You could do the same for any object. It's just syntactic sugar on top of [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). You could just as easily create getters/setters for the camera object.