# How to trap getOwnPropertyDescriptor on native object's prototype object?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

My target object is `Notification.prototype` and I need to proxy the `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` calls to it. I'm unable decide where to assign my proxy into.

```js
var myProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, key) {
      console.log("GET CALLED");
      return target[key];
    },
    ownKeys: function() {
      console.log("Own Keys called");
      return ["a", "b"];
    },
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor: function(target, key) {
       console.log("Property Descriptor Called");
       return { value: this.get(target, key), enumerable: true, configurable: true };
    }
});
```

Do I need to proxy this `Object.prototype.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` itself to achieve this effect?

Comment: The `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` trap looks to work just fine, [keeping in mind the restrictions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.getownpropertydescriptor) with a Proxy

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes but I don't know where to assign my trap.

Comment: The `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` trap in your code works. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: It's not possibly to replace native objects by proxied versions of themselves. How exactly are you using notifications and what do you want to intercept on them?

Comment: @CertainPerformance The problem is I need to override Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor for Notification.prototype object universally and  I can't assign this proxy to Notification.prototype directly

Comment: Does something like this works? `Notification.prototype = new Proxy(Notification.prototype, { ... })`

Comment: @adiga No, it doesn't. Native instances are created from the original prototype directly, not looking up `.prototype` like a constructor call.

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to hide a property on a native object and I need to override the behavior of Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (and others) ... I don't mean to replace native objects

Comment: @jeffbRTC Which property, on which specific native object? As I said, you cannot replace (or "modify") `Notification.prototype`. Instead you need to intercept the creation of the concrete instance to mess with it.

Comment: @Bergi this is a native prototype? This one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification ?

Comment: @Bergi Notification.prototype itself. I have a custom property defined on it and I need to hide it.

Comment: @adiga Yes, it's a builtin prototype

Comment: @jeffbRTC Hide it from where/whom? Why did you define it in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi From websites that loop over the prototype. I'm doing some abuse blocking script. I have to define it because to maintain state.

Comment: @jeffbRTC If you want to count notifications or store some other stuff, use a symbol-keyed property, or a `WeakMap`/`WeakSet`. Do not mess with the prototype in environments you don't own.

Comment: @Bergi Can you add an example for both two?

Comment: @Bergi Env is mine, my browser.

Comment: @jeffbRTC https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533611/1048572

Comment: @Bergi I like Weekmaps but does it actually sync the object or just keep copy of a some old state?

Comment: @jeffbRTC What do you mean by "sync"? You still haven't shown the code of what you want to use with `Notification.prototype`

Comment: @Bergi Well, does it sync the object signature to the map? I mean can it differ objects?

Comment: @jeffbRTC Objects are reference values that are compared by identity, not their shape or property values. In maps and otherwise.

Comment: @Bergi Bravo! It's working. Lovely. You may  write an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I can't put that as an answer to "*How to trap getOwnPropertyDescriptor on native object's prototype object?*" though