# How do we get access to a private variable in ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

Below we define a private variable `boy` for a would-be instance of the class 'Forrest'. By doing this JavaScript signals of no mistakes. But neither the instance, nor `Forrest.prototype` or  `Forrest` function object itself show no signs of hosting this variable.

```
class Forrest {
  constructor() {
    let boy = "Bobby";
    girl: "Marry";
  }
}

const f = new Forrest();
```

However, we can easily get access to this private `boy` variable via vanilla JS constructor function.

```
function Forrest() { 
  let boy = "Bobby"; 
  this.getBoy = function() { 
    console.log(boy);
  } 
} 

const f = new Forrest();
f.getBoy(); // Bobby
```

How do we get access to this private (local) variable in ES6 class?

Comment: `girl: "Marry" ` is not a property. It's a [*labeled statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and does nothing. To create a property you would have to do `this.girl = "Marry"`.

Comment: And `boy` is just a local variable with no persistence beyond the scope of the `constructor` function.

Comment: …and `let boy` creates a *local* variable that is not stored on the object but is only visible inside the constructor.

Comment: (Btw, this is not different from ES5)

Comment: Your "vanilla constructor" example has no resemblance to the class example. `f` is not an instance of `Forrest`, it's an anonymous function object.

Comment: Hint: there's no such thing as "private variables" in Javascript. Private fields are a thing though, but they look like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237988/476

Comment: Interesting. Thank you all for your comments. Yet, it seems that I can get access to a private variable via vanilla Function constructor, unlike in ES6 class. Here is an example: function Forrest() {
  let boy = "Bobby";
  (function() {
    console.log(boy);
  })()
}

var f = new Forrest();
f instanceof Forrest // true

Comment: What does *that* demonstrate?! The `inner` function is just an IIFE which you might as well remove entirely. Then it's just down to defining a local function variable and logging it.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to get the same access to a 'closed' variable in ES6 class?

Comment: You don't. You're not even *really* getting any access to it in your "vanilla" example. You can't get both an instance of `Forrest` *and* the value of `boy` when you declare `boy` as a local function variable. `boy` needs to be a property of the instance of `Forrest`. As the answer below shows, that's done with `this.boy = 'Bobby'`, and that's in fact the same for ES6 and vanilla.

Comment: deceze, but I CAN "get both an instance of Forrest and the value of boy" by this:  function Forrest() {
  let boy = "Bobby";
  this.getBoy = function() {
    console.log(boy);
  }
}
var f = new Forrest();
f.getBoy() // Bobby      Can I do the same in ES6 class?

Comment: Well, now you've added a property to the object that lets you access the value. Not much different than `this.boy = 'Booby'`. You're just using a closure instead of the bare value. Try *assigning* a new value to `boy` with just this; you can't. You only have indirect access to `boy`. You can do the same in an ES6 class with `this.getBoy = ...` in `constructor`.

Comment: Thank you, deceze. "this.getBoy = function() {
      console.log(boy)
    }" inside a contructor() {} will do the job of accessing a private variable in ES6 class.

Answer (score 1):

`let boy` is a variable only valid within the constructor's scope

`girl: "Marry"` is not a property at all

This is how you initialize and access attributes

```js
class Forrest {
  constructor() {
    this.boy = "Bobby"
    this.girl = "Marry"
  }
}

const f = new Forrest();
console.log(f.boy)
console.log(f.girl)
```

Comment: We can get this 'boy' variable via vanilla constructor function. Why we cannot get it via ES6 class?
function Forrest() {
       let boy = "Bobby";
       
       return function() {
         console.log(boy);
       }
     }
     
     var f = new Forrest();
     f(); // Bobby

Comment: @Maksym Because that "constructor function" doesn't return an *object instance* like the class does, it returns a *closure*. Very different examples.

Answer (score 0):

// The answer turns out to be:

```
class Forrest {
  constructor() {
    let boy = "Bobby"
    this.getBoy = function() { // This is it!
      console.log(boy)
    }
  }

}

const f = new Forrest()
f.getBoy() // Bobby
```