# why typescript class expose all private members?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm confused with typescript class, the private member doesn't work as it should.

```
class TClass {

  public pu = 1;
  private pv = 2

  constructor(private ar = 1) {

  }

}

const f1 = new TClass();
console.log({ ...f1 })
```

the output of this is

```
[LOG]: {
  "ar": 1,
  "pu": 1,
  "pv": 2
}
```

as you can see all the private members are exposed!

but if I want to write a custom class I could use something like this

```
const JClass= function(ar=1){
  const pv=2;
  this.pu=1;
};

const f2= new JClass();
console.log({...f2})
```

and the output will be

```
[LOG]: {
  "pu": 1
}
```

if you want to play here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=21&pln=16&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqDC4rQN4Cg3WgBwK4CMQBLYHXaAXmgEYBuTHAJyIDcwAXAUxxcugCYMWYAHsAdhHaNcwdiMYAKbMzZdoYRn2oBKVEOgBfDEbSiJ7aADNqfMZwDucRJAgLt9MxBEhOAOhAiAOYKKNC%204daG2him4pLQAFLOUFSWuGKyROIKGhQ66MJxFtgsFPz0WOwAFkQQvnh59Ab0seZW-FR2jklIru6tXj7%20QSHhvpb8BtExQA)

so my question is how to make the typescript really respect the meaning of private?

Comment: `private` just enforces the rules within ts. It will throw an error when you access it `f1.pv`. But, if you check the, transpiled javascript which ultimately runs in the browser, there is no difference between private and public properties. It is just another key on the object. (Yet: [Private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields))

Comment: you can make properties private by using #: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes check this accepted answer