# Javascript Stack Linked list implementation

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am confused in this javascript linked list implementation, in the pop() function how can we do this.top.next. The next attribute is inside node class so how can we access it with a stack class attribute top?

```
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.top = null;
    this.bottom = null;
    this.length = null;
  }

  peek() {
    return this.top;
  }
  push(value) {
    const New_node = new Node(value);
     if (this.top === null) {
       this.top = New_node;
      this.bottom = New_node;
    } else {
      New_node.next = this.top;
      this.top = New_node;
    }
    this.length++;
    return this;
  }

  pop() {
    if (this.top === null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      this.top = this.top.next;
    }
    this.length--;
    return this;
}
const myStack = new Stack();
myStack.push("google");
myStack.push("facebook");
myStack.push("netflix");
myStack.pop();
console.log(myStack);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The next attribute is inside node class so how can we access it with a stack class attribute top?

This is possible only when the stack is not empty. So initially, when `this.top` is `null` this would not work -- the reason why in the `pop` function this case is handled differently via the `if` statement.

However, if the stack is not empty, then it means a `push` had been executed earlier on, and there we can see that `this.top` is assigned a node instance: `New_node`, which in turn was assigned `new Node(value)`. So once that has been done, `this.top` is a node, and its node properties can be accessed with expressions like `this.top.value` and `this.top.next`.

Also realise that `value` and `next` are "public" properties, and so there is no problem in accessing them from within another class. This is the default. [Private properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes) have been a later addition to the JavaScript language, and have distinct names (hash-prefix).