# Maps vs Objects in ES6, When to use?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

[Ref: MDN Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

> Use maps over objects when keys are unknown until run time, and when
>   all keys are the same type and all values are the same type.
>
> Use objects when there is logic that operates on individual elements.

### **Question:**

**What is an applicable example of using Maps over objects?  in particular, "when would keys be unknown until runtime?"**

```
var myMap = new Map();

var keyObj = {},
    keyFunc = function () { return 'hey'},
    keyString = "a string";

// setting the values
myMap.set(keyString, "value associated with 'a string'");
myMap.set(keyObj, "value associated with keyObj");
myMap.set(keyFunc, "value associated with keyFunc");

console.log(myMap.get(keyFunc));
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. As I set a function as a value.  @JonathanLonowski can you think of when I should do that tho :(  it's tough thinking of usecases.

Comment: You might use it where you have say a DOM element that you want to associate some data with using an Object. Instead of using, say the element's ID as the key in an object, you can use the element itself as a key in a Map so you don't care whether the element has an ID (or any other unique identifier other than an object reference) or not.

Comment: @RobG just a little addition: in that case it's a `WeakMap` that might also be helpful.

Comment: @RobG Use the whole element as a key?  what if that element mutates some how like a class gets added to the element sometime? wouldnt that conflict as the unique identifier?  This does sound nice.  If you can make an example I'll mark it correct :)

Comment: I don't think so, if mutating the object broke the relationship Maps would be useless. I have half an answer but I don't have time to finish it for a while…

Comment: I think this suggests to use objects as/for records and Maps for every other kind of mapping. With records I mean a data struct with a fixed set of fields, such as a user object which has the fields `name` and `id` for example.

Comment: When I was reading that MDN page, the bullet-point list of use cases was much more helpful than the paragraph you quoted. Certainly in relation to the question posed in your title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map vs Object in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> What is an applicable example of using Maps over objects?

I think you've given one good example already: You at least need to use `Map`s when you are using objects (including Function objects) as keys.

> in particular, "when would keys be unknown until runtime?"

Whenever they are not known at compile time. In short, you should always use a `Map` when you need a [key-value *collection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). A good indicator that you need a collection is when you add and remove values dynamically from the collection, and especially when you don't know those values beforehand (e.g. they're read from a database, input by the user, etc).

In contrast, you should be using objects when you know which and how many properties the object has while writing the code - when their shape is static. As @Felix has put it: when you need a [record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)). A good indicator for needing that is when the fields have different types, and when you never need to use bracket notation (or expect a limited set of property names in it).

Comment: Or from another point of view: Whenever you need to iterate over your object's properties at the data level (e.g. `for..of`) instead of the program level (e.g. `for..in`) use a `Map`. More information concerning this terms [in this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38777177/6445533).

Comment: I will add as comment also the fact that anytime you don't know what kind of type your key will be and you don't expect string as key data types, then use map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600157/maps-vs-objects-in-es6-when-to-use

Answer (score 28):

I think that with ES2015's `Map` only two reasons are left to use plain objects:

- You don't want to iterate over the properties of an object type at all
- or you do but the property order doesn't matter and you can [distinguish the program from the data level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38777177/6445533) when iterating

When is the property order unimportant?

- if you have only a single value and some functions that should be associated explicitly with it (like `Promise` - which is a proxy for a future value - and `then`/`catch`)
- if you have a struct/record-like data structure with a static set of properties known at "compile time" (usually structs/records aren't iterable)

In all other cases you might consider using `Map`, because it preserves property order and separates the program (all properties assigned to the `Map` object) from the data level (all entries in the `Map` itself).

What are the drawbacks of `Map`?

- you lose the concise object literal syntax
- you need custom replacers for JSON.stringyfy
- you lose destructuring, which is more useful with static data structures  anyway

Comment: This line concerns me very much: "it is probably slower than pure, hashmap-like objects" I thought of replacing all my objects with maps because of performance improvements. But you say it's slower...

Comment: You're right. `Map` is probably faster, because it is based purely on a hash, whereas `Object` is a bit more complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

> Use maps over objects when keys are unknown until run time, and when all keys are the same type and all values are the same type.

I have no idea why someone would write something so obviously wrong. I have to say, people are finding more and more wrong and/or questionable content on MDN these days.

Nothing in that sentence is correct. The main reason to use maps is when you want object-valued keys. The idea that the values should be the same type is absurd--although they might be, of course. The idea that one shouldn't use objects when keys are unknown until run time is equally absurd.

Comment: I don't see what's so absurd about the idea? When you need collections, they are typically strictly typed (there might be exceptions, of course). Also, I think that no more using objects for collections (when `Map` is available) is good advice.

Comment: To that collections are typically strictly typed is logically distinct from saying that something strictly typed should be a collection.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's put a bit odd, but the idea is fine. I guess that they thought "keys are unknown until run time" already makes a collection. Any idea for a better phrasing?

Comment: Agreed. MDN has very good documentation, but they should stick to documenting APIs doc and not try to give programming advices.

Answer (score 6):

`Object`s are similar to `Map`s in that both let you set keys to values, retrieve those values, delete keys, and detect whether something is stored at a key. Because of this (and because there were no built-in alternatives), `Object`s have been used as `Map`s historically; however, there are important differences that make using a `Map` preferable in certain cases:

- The keys of an `Object` are `String`s and `Symbol`s, whereas they can be
  any value for a `Map`, including functions, objects, and any primitive.
- The keys in `Map` are ordered while keys added to object are not. Thus,
  when iterating over it, a `Map` object returns keys in order of
  insertion.
- You can get the size of a `Map` easily with the `size` property, while
  the number of properties in an `Object` must be determined manually.
- A `Map` is an iterable and can thus be directly iterated, whereas
  iterating over an `Object` requires obtaining its keys in some fashion
  and iterating over them.
- An `Object` has a prototype, so there are default keys in the map that
  could collide with your keys if you're not careful. As of ES5 this
  can be bypassed by using `map = Object.create(null)`, but this is
  seldom done.
- A `Map` may perform better in scenarios involving frequent addition and
  removal of key pairs.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 5):

One of the difference between `Map` and `Object` is:

`Map` can use complex data type as its key. like this:

```
const fn = function() {}
const m = new Map([[document.body, 'stackoverflow'], [fn, 'redis']]);

m.get(document.body) // 'stackoverflow'
m.get(fn) //'redis'
```

**watch out:** For complex data type, If you want to get the value, you must pass the same reference as the key.

`Object`, it only accept simple data type(`number`, `string`) as its key.

```
const a = {};
a[document.body] = 'stackoverflow';

console.log(a) //{[object HTMLBodyElement]: "stackoverflow"}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is a duplicate of  but until it's closed, here's [my answer from over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript/42040803#42040803):

In addition to the other answers, I've found that Maps are more unwieldy and verbose to operate with than objects.

```
obj[key] += x
// vs.
map.set(map.get(key) + x)
```

This is important, because shorter code is faster to read, more directly expressive, and better [kept in the programmer's head](http://paulgraham.com/head.html).

Another aspect: because set() returns the map, not the value, it's impossible to chain assignments.

```
foo = obj[key] = x;  // Does what you expect
foo = map.set(key, x)  // foo !== x; foo === map
```

Debugging maps is also more painful. Below, you can't actually see what keys are in the map. You'd have to write code to do that.

[image: Good luck evaluating a Map Iterator]

Objects can be evaluated by any IDE:

[image: WebStorm evaluating an object]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "*What is an applicable example of using Maps over objects?*" at all

Comment: Please don't cross-post your answers. And no, the question is not a duplicate.