# How Map in javascript cause memory leak while WeakMap is not?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I go through the documentation of Map and WeakMap of javascript from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections).

but in this ([Why WeakMap?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)) topic I did not get second point that is how WeakMap prevent memory leak while Map does not.

will somebody explain it briefly with some sort of example.

--edits--

Actually I wanted to know how WeakMap holds weak references or how it is implemented.

but now i got this answer and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604168/whats-the-difference-between-es6-map-and-weakmap/50554841#50554841)

Answer (score 3):

Consider an implementation for a `LinkedList` or a `Tree`. You might not want to expose `next`, `last`, `children`, or `parent` as a property, but instead make it a property accessor that checks a static `WeakMap` for the existence of such relationships. This way, your implementation allows the relationships to maintain weak connections.

HTML elements are a good way of explaining this. Let's say you partially implement an HTML element:

```js
const HTMLElement = (() => {
  const children = new WeakMap()

  class Node {
    constructor () {
      children.set(this, [])
    }

    get children () {
      return children.get(this)
    }

    appendChild (element) {
      children.get(this).push(element)
      return element
    }

    removeChild (element) {
      const elements = children.get(this)
      elements.splice(elements.indexOf(element), 1)
      return element
    }
  }

  return class HTMLElement extends Node {
    constructor (tag) {
      super()
      this.tagName = tag.toUpperCase()
    }

    toString () {
      return `<${this.tagName}>${children.get(this).join('')}</${this.tagName}>`
    }
  }
})()

{
  const p = new HTMLElement('p')

  p.appendChild(new HTMLElement('a'))
  p.appendChild(new HTMLElement('span'))

  console.log(`${p}`)
}
// a and span get GC'd when reference to p is lost
console.log(typeof p)
```

If `children` was a `Map`, you'd have a memory leak when the reference to `p` is lost, because the others would still have strong references since `HTMLElement` is still accessible.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in the article you linked

> By contrast, native WeakMaps hold "weak" references to key objects,
>   which means that they do not prevent garbage collection in case there
>   would be no other reference to the key object.

WeakMaps do not directly reference the keys, and therefore when all other references of the keys run out, the keys can still be garbage-collected, therefore no memory leak